# Whats the difference between itsio and ESP in gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, routes, istio

Both seem to do the same things. From what I've gathered Istio does routing at Inngress level and ESP at container level. I'm still understanding Istio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/glossary#extensible_service_proxy):

> ### Extensible Service Proxy
>
> The Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) is an Nginx-based high-performance, scalable proxy that runs in front of an OpenAPI or gRPC API backend and provides API management features such as authentication, monitoring, and logging. See  [About Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/about-cloud-endpoints)  and  [Endpoints: Architectural overview](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/architecture-overview)  for more information.
>
> ### Extensible Service Proxy V2 Beta
>
> The Extensible Service Proxy V2 Beta (ESPv2 Beta) is an  [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/)-based high-performance, scalable proxy that runs in front of an OpenAPI API backend and provides API management features such as authentication, monitoring, and logging. See  [About Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/about-cloud-endpoints)  and  [Endpoints: Architectural overview](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/architecture-overview)  for more information.
>
> ESPv2 Beta supports version 2 of the  [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md). ESPv2 Beta does not currently support  [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/).
>
> ESPv2 Beta is only supported for use for the Beta versions of Endpoints for  [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions)  and for  [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run). ESPv2 Beta is not supported for Endpoints for App Engine, GKE, Compute Engine, or Kubernetes.

According to istio github [documentation](https://github.com/istio/istio#introduction):

> ### Introduction
>
> Istio is an open platform for providing a uniform way to integrate microservices, manage traffic flow across microservices, enforce policies and aggregate telemetry data. Istio's control plane provides an abstraction layer over the underlying cluster management platform, such as Kubernetes.
>
> Istio is composed of these components:
>
> - **Envoy**  - Sidecar proxies per microservice to handle ingress/egress traffic between services in the cluster and from a service to external services. The proxies form a  *secure microservice mesh*  providing a rich set of functions like discovery, rich layer-7 routing, circuit breakers, policy enforcement and telemetry recording/reporting functions.
>
>   > Note: The service mesh is not an overlay network. It simplifies and enhances how microservices in an application talk to each other over the network provided by the underlying platform.
> - **Mixer**  - Central component that is leveraged by the proxies and microservices to enforce policies such as authorization, rate limits, quotas, authentication, request tracing and telemetry collection.
> - **Pilot**  - A component responsible for configuring the proxies at runtime.
> - **Citadel**  - A centralized component responsible for certificate issuance and rotation.
> - **Citadel Agent**  - A per-node component responsible for certificate issuance and rotation.
> - **Galley**- Central component for validating, ingesting, aggregating, transforming and distributing config within Istio.
> - **Operator**- The component provides user friendly options to operate the Istio service mesh.
>
> Istio currently supports Kubernetes and Consul-based environments. We plan support for additional platforms such as Cloud Foundry, and Mesos in the near future.

The ESP v2 Beta is also based on Envoy proxy just like Istio. However there are advanced features that Istio has that ESP v2 does not have yet as it is still in beta. As for ESP v1 it is more like nginx ingress. All of these tools are able to do the routing tasks, however each tool has different mechanisms under the hood and offer different amount of configuration flexibility and complexity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In few words, ESP is an API Gateway for North-south traffic, based on Open API specs. Istio is a service mesh, for managing routing and security into this mesh (north-south and east-west, a mesh!).